# mod_jk between apache and tomcat: making sure 8080 requests still go to tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, tomcat, port, mod-jk

This question follows a `mod_jk` configuration question asked [earlier](https://serverfault.com/questions/313448/mod-jk-configuration-for-both-apache-and-tomcat-on-same-server). I have managed to to have `http://mywebsite.com/MyTomcatApp/` go to Tomcat while having `http://mywebsite.com/` go to Apache.

However, my requests to `http://mywebsite.com:8080/` (to access Tomcat's manager for example) don't work anymore. How can/should I update my `000-default` file mentioned in my previous question to keep access to Tomcat's manager under this configuration?

**P.S.**: Yes, I am a newbie/not a sysadmin.

Comment: What output did you get? Also take a look at `catalina.out` to see what it say.

Comment: @quanta I am getting a blank page and when I 'View Page Source' it is blank (no content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think understand the role of `JkUnMount` better. I changed my `000-default` file to:

```
JkMount /* worker1
JkUnMount /*.html worker1
```

All goes to tomcat and I have access to the manager again. The default Apache html page is still served.